# Is there any way to upgrade Windows Vista Home Premium to Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

It's not supported in the official upgrade matrix, but is there some way to change a config file and make this happen anyway?  I know it can be upgraded to Ultimate so Professional would seem to be a business choice rather than a technical one.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this would be to <strike>upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium as a demo and then upgrade to Windows 7 Professional.  You could then put in your key.</strike>  I will test this in VM and get back to you with confirmation.

You have to create an All-In-One version of the Windows 7 install DVD to do this.  Instuctions can be found here:

http://www.vista123.net/content/how-create-windows-7-aio-all-one-dvd-or-merge-all-editions-windows-7-single-dvd

**UPDATE**: *I am wrong!* `:(` If you try to do what I recommend, you get this message:

> To upgrade from one edition of Windows
>   7 to another edition of Windows 7, use
>   Windows Anytime Upgrade. Cancel the
>   upgrade, open the Start menu, and
>   search for Windows Anytime Upgrade.

I haven't been able to find a way around it.

Comment: I think that might work...  Can you use a retail professional key for anytime upgrade?

Comment: The keys used with Windows Anytime Upgrade (WAU) are only for use with WAU. When you use it, it says you can't use the product key. Look at my update for some more bad news.

Comment: I'm picking this as the best answer because you did some work verifying what you said.  Even if it doesn't give me a solution, it helps me narrow down my options.

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest is, you get the Windows 7 Home Premium Upgrade, and use the [Anytime Upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Upgrade-to-another-edition-of-Windows-7-by-using-Windows-Anytime-Upgrade) feature to upgrade to Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Isn't that more expensive than just getting professional?

Comment: yes it would seem so, about $10

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do what you want. Microsoft has clamped down on upgrade paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade your computer running Windows Vista Home Premium to Windows 7 Pro, what you'll need to is a custom or clean install from upgrade media. This option doesn't preserve your programs, files or settings. It's sometimes called a "clean" installation for that reason.

The [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) tool creates a single file containing your files and settings for back up to external media and subsequent restore on the fresh OS.

[This](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-vista-to-windows-7-custom) is the MS custom installation guide for a Vista to '7' custom install.

Comment: I think you mean you can't upgrade from XP to 7.  You can upgrade from certain version of Vista to 7.  I've done it.

Comment: Clarified my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "Upgrade" from Vista Home Premium to 7 Professional directly. Since it's best to do a full, clean install when upgrading to any version of Windows; I'd recommend just buying 7 Professional and doing a Full install.

And, Yes, you can do a Full install if you only have the Upgrade media. Microsoft says you can't, but the following link explains otherwise.

http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp